# Macro not working when I "Call" it from another macro, but does work when I select it individually

Tags: excel, vba, method-call

I have a formatting macro below:

```
Sub Colour_whole_sheet()

Dim lastRow As Long
Dim lastColumn As Long

lastRow = Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
lastColumn = Range("A3").End(xlToRight).Column

'Colour alternate rows purple / white
For Each cell In Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(lastRow, lastColumn))
    If cell.Row Mod 2 = 1 Then
        cell.Interior.Color = RGB(242, 230, 255)
    Else
        cell.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
    End If
Next cell

End Sub
```

It doesn't run when I call it from another macro, which is just:

```
Sub Run_macros()

[A bunch of other subs]
Call Colour_whole_sheet
[A bunch of other subs]

End Sub
```

It doesn't come up with an error - it just doesn't do anything. But when I select it specifically on its own, from View > Macros > View Macros > Run, it works fine.

Do you know why this might be?

EDIT:

```
Sub Colour_whole_sheet()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Calendar")

Dim lastRow As Long
Dim lastColumn As Long

lastRow = ws.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
lastColumn = ws.Range("A3").End(xlToRight).Column

'Colour alternate rows purple / white
For Each cell In ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, 1), ws.Cells(lastRow, lastColumn))
    If cell.Row Mod 2 = 1 Then
        cell.Interior.Color = RGB(242, 230, 255)
    Else
        cell.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
    End If
Next cell

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here `Range("A1")` is not specified in which worksheet this range is. **Always** specify a worksheet for **all** your `Range()`, `Cells()`, `Rows()` and `Columns()` objects.

Otherwise it is very likely that your code runs on the wrong worksheet. Note that this is applicable to **all** your macros (not just this one). Check if you have specified a worksheet **everywhere**, or your code might randomly work or fail.

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") 'your sheet name here
```

Then adjust the following lines:

```
lastRow = ws.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
lastColumn = ws.Range("A3").End(xlToRight).Column

For Each cell In ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, 1), ws.Cells(lastRow, lastColumn))
```

Also note that you can [format an Excel table](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/format-an-excel-table-6789619f-c889-495c-99c2-2f971c0e2370) to get rows alternated colored.

---

Additional notes:

The method you used is not reliable in finding the last used row/column. Better do it the other way round. Start in the very last row and go `xlUp`.

```
lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 'Last used row
lastColumn = ws.Cells(3, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column 'last used column in row 3
```

Also you don't need to go through all cells. Looping throug rows would do.

```
Dim i As Long
For i = 1 To lastRow
    If i Mod 2 = 1 Then
        ws.Rows(i).Interior.Color = RGB(242, 230, 255)
    Else
        ws.Rows(i)..Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
    End If
Next i
```

or if you don't want to color the whole row but only up to the last used column

```
ws.Cells(i, lastColumn).Interior.Color
```

---

Note that coloring each row on on its own can slow down a lot if there are many rows. Therefore I suggest to collect all even/uneven rows in a reference and color it at once.

```
lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 'Last used row
lastColumn = ws.Cells(3, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column 'last used 

Dim EvenRows As Range
Dim OddRows As Range

Dim i As Long
For i = 1 To lastRow
    If i Mod 2 = 1 Then
        If OddRows Is Nothing Then
            Set OddRows = ws.Rows(i)
        Else
            Set OddRows = Union(OddROws, ws.Rows(i))
        End If
    Else
        If EvenRows Is Nothing Then
            Set EvenRows = ws.Rows(i)
        Else
            Set EvenRows = Union(EvenRows, ws.Rows(i))
        End If
    End If
Next i

If Not OddRows Is Nothing Then OddRows.Interior.Color = RGB(242, 230, 255)
If Not EvenRows Is Nothing Then EvenRows.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
```

Comment: Hi, I've edited as you suggested, but it's now not working even when I call it individually - have I done something wrong?

Comment: @LizH see my edit. Make sure you don't use `On Error Resume Next` anywhere without proper error handling!

Comment: @LizH Have another look at my edit. The final solution should be much faster since it colors all the rows at once and not row-by-row.

Comment: I'm glad OP found a solution, but nearly most of this one derives from mine… quite discouraging

Comment: @HTH Please note that I wrote my second edit at the same time you wrote your answer, and I did not take anything from your code (my approach is actually even a way different from yours). Don't take it personally you even got my vote for your answer.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ, well your second edit was 2 minutes after mine, your 3rd 10 minutes later more and your last approach only added `Union()` instead of row by row processing. But the discouraging thing to me is the OP's choice.

Comment: @HTH Yes, 2 min later means overlapping in writing/posting (it does not pop up immediately), and it happens a lot here. Since my approach was a way different from yours I did't remove it. Actually my last approach which is an improvement of my second and that *"only"* added `Union()` speeds up the whole process **a lot** and that is probably why the OP decided to change his choice. Anyway there is nothing wrong having 2 answers with 2 different approaches.

Comment: @HTH Actually I like your approach using it as a function, as this makes it re-usable. So it is worth to have multiple different answers. In the end the "best" (in the meaning of speed and reusability) would be a combination of your's using a function and mine using union. People here usually up-vote for every good answer (which will give you the points). The mark as solution is more like "this is the solution the OP finally used".

Answer (score 2):

you might be after this revision of your code

```
Sub Colour_whole_sheet(Optional sht As Variant)

    If IsMissing(sht) Then Set sht = ActiveSheet ' if no argument is passed assume ActiveSheet

    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim lastColumn As Long
    Dim i As Long

    With sht ' reference passed/assumed sheet object
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row ' best way to get a column last used cell row index
        lastColumn = .Cells(3, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column ' best way to get a row last used cell column index

        'Colour alternate rows purple / white
        With .Range("A1", Cells(lastRow, lastColumn)) ' reference all your range
            .Interior.Color = vbWhite ' color it white
            For i = 1 To .Rows.Count Step 2 ' loop through referenced range uneven rows
                .Rows(i).Interior.Color = RGB(242, 230, 255) ' color them with purple
            Next
        End With
    End With

End Sub
```

as you can see:

- it always references some sheet(be it passed through sub argument or be it the active one)
- it doesn't loop through all cells, but just through uneven rows

Comment: Why not `sht As Worksheet`? I mean worksheets are the only thing this procedure can handle so it should be defined as specific as possible.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ, because passing it as `Variant` allows the consumer to pass no argument at all

Comment: @htc No that's not correct, actually `Optional` allows the user to pass no argument at all. `Variant` just specifies which type can be passed as argument. And that type must be `Worksheet`. If the user passes anything else than `Worksheet` or `Nothing` the procedure will fail. Define `Optional sht As Worksheet` and `If sht Is Nothing Then Set sht = ActiveSheet` will force a worksheet. Give it a try, that works perfectly and is even more safe code.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ, you're right and my previous comment was innacurate.